# Better print quality by using built-in typeface list in Postscript?

Tags: printing, fonts, postscript

I am generating prints for an older printer, a Laserjet 4si MX that has a Postscript engine. This engine is version 2011.110

The engine reports that it has about 35 built-in fonts. The fonts listed are things like:

```
ITC Avant Garde Gothic Book
ITC Bookman Demi
Courier
Helvetica
New Century Schoolbook Bold
Palatino
Symbol
Times Roman
ITC Zapf Chancery Medium Italic

etc and so on
```

I think the engine also supports downloaded fonts.

To maximize print quality would I be advised to program to print in these particular built-in fonts, or can I use operating system fonts just as well? My concern is that using an operating-system provided font will be lower print quality than the built-in fonts.

Comment: This question is one of those "we can't tell you, just test it" questions. We don't have access to your hardware and so can't tell you how it'll specifically behave (because old printers are tempramental). Just make a PDF with the same sentence in all typefaces including the not-built-in-ones you're considering, print the one or two pages that takes up, and just see which get printed nicely and which don't. That'll be a better answer than anyone here can give you, and you can store the pages with the printer for future reference.

Comment: @Mike has the right idea. But be sure to post your results as an answer!

Answer (score 0):

I worked at Adobe Systems, in the PostScript printer division, when (I believe) this printer's PostScript interpreter was developed. The font names you give match the names of fonts from the [PostScript Level 2 core font set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostScript_fonts#Core_Font_Set). If you send a page description which asks for the built-in fonts, it will generate high-quality results. If you send a page description which downloads fonts (or font subsets) properly, it will also generate high-quality results. It was routine for this class of printer to print with downloaded fonts.

But, the quality of the result depends also on the quality of PostScript language page description you are sending, and the way that page description downloads fonts. That in turns depends on which operating system, which application, which printer driver, and which fonts, you are using. You don't tell us this.  This is an old printer. It may be that a new OS or application won't have support for delivering fonts the way this printer expects.

Also, the meaning of "quality" depends on the requirements of the person evaluating it. By "print quality" do you mean smoothness of outlines, or ability to match a desired font design? Do speed of printing, or compactness of page description data, play a role?

As [Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans](https://stackoverflow.com/users/740553/mike-pomax-kamermans) says, "we can't tell you, so test it, and report your results".  What do you want us to tell you that your simple test will not?